# Can't run nestjs build without node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm developing a **Nestjs** micro-service and need to run the build in **dist** folder using below command and it's working fine

```
node dist/main.js
```

Problem is, above command not working without the **node_modules** folder. Why can't we run the the build folder(**dist**) without node_modules folder?

This is the error I'm getting
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Node code, which uses the node_modules folder to **search for modules.** It cannot run without it. You could try using something like [`pkg`](https://npmjs.org/pkg) to package it into an executable. The dist folder just contains code, not modules.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Node.js are depended on package.json for finding modules, which also depend on node_modules that store the module. Maybe you want to compile it as one ? Try this https://github.com/vercel/ncc. I never use it for Nest.js before, but you can try it.

Answer (score 1):

You can only run it without node_modules by rewriting the webpack.config.js, you may check this template [nestjs-v9-webpack-boilerplate](https://github.com/kenso312/nestjs-v9-webpack-boilerplate)

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.